# overwrite specific Decorators for all Zend_Form Objects

Tags: php, zend-form, decorator, zend-decorators

i am working on styling a project and everybody used Zend_Form and default Elements. This makes it impossible to style submit buttons.
Therefore i would like to overwrite the default Zend_Form Decorator for submit buttons, but without changing every line where a Zend_Form is created.

Is that possible?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to ***subclass `Zend_Form_Element_Submit`*** and use `loadDefaultDecorators()` to set the default decorators for your submits:

```
class My_Form_Element_Submit extends Zend_Form_Element_Submit
{
    public function loadDefaultDecorators()
    {
        // set your default decorators for the submit element       
        $decorators = $this->getDecorators();
        if (empty($decorators)) {
            $this->setDecorators(array(
                'ViewHelper',
                array(
                    array('field' => 'HtmlTag'),
                    array(
                        'tag'   => 'span',
                        'class' => 'some-wrapper-class'
                    ) 
                )
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

The above decorators would result in ***HTML code looking something like this***, allowing you to easily style your submit button:

```
<span class="some-wrapper-class"> 
    <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save">
</span>
```

Comment: No, subclassing is exactly not what i want.

Comment: @Andresch and why is that? If you provide a reason of why it isn't what you want, I, or someone else is better able to help you.

Comment: Sorry @Aron Rotteveel i was mistaken. Actually it is what i was looking for. Kind of. Thanks.